# server.id not blocking duplicate message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

is there any way when the serverid identifies the one corresponding to the "if" it does not send the duplicate message? he ends up sending both messages, he doesn't block the second message when he identifies the server.id

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => { 

const server = message.guild;

    if (server.id === '817098820567302145') {
        message.channel.send(`stop message`);
    }

    message.channel.send('message duplicate')
}
```

Comment: Just include a `return` inside the if statement so that it returns, if the condition is satisfied. What return does is, it stop further execution of the code.

Answer (score -1):

As per the details of logic that you want to implement, everything looks good considering the comparison above. I'm pretty sure that the issue is either on retrieving the `id` from `message.guild` or it is actually sending some unexpected value in arguments. Double check it again :)

Comment: The duplicate message is sent because of sequencing. The if-condition is fired then moves on to the next line.